# Highcharts userOptions does not update after changing the chart title

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to store the chart userOptions (JSON string) in a database for later use.  But after I change something like the chart title userOptions doesn't update for re-saving back to the database.  The Chart GUI updates ok, but not chartOptions.

Thank you very much for any help that you can offer!

1) Load userOptions from the db and build the chart:

```
userOptions = {
    "chart":{type:"line"},
    "title":{"text":"Original Title"},
    ...
};
chart = Highcharts.chart('chart_container',userOptions);
```

Then dynamically change the chart title:

```
chart.setTitle({text:'New Title'}):
```

The chart GUI updates by userOptions remains unchanged:

```
userOptions = chart.userOptions;
delete userOptions.series;
userOptions = JSON.stringify(CuserOptions);

userOptions = {
    "chart":{type:"line"},
    "title":{"text":"Original Title"},
    ...
};
```

I'm thinking that I'm missing something that's obvious to everyone else.

Comment: Thanks Wojciech.  That was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **current state** of the chart is stored in the `chart.options` property, `chart.userOptions` is used only to **initialize** the chart. Check demo I posted you below.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="btn">Change title</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var userOptions = {
  title: {
    text: 'Original Title'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }],
};

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', userOptions);

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    console.group('chart-options');
  console.log('old chart title: ', chart.options.title.text);

  chart.setTitle({
    text: 'New Title'
  });

  console.log('options: ', chart.options);
  console.log('new chart title: ', chart.options.title.text);
  console.groupEnd('chart-options');
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/u7hc40pj/1/